# Django paypal checkout for WHOLE cart

Tags: django, paypal

I made a Django online-store site and I need to include paypal checkout system for the cart, but solutions I found online either just for one item only(Buy Now buttons) or something like django-paypal-cart, which is not well-documented and I can't figure out how to make it to the checkout.

Please, give me some hint, maybe good article about how to make your cart items go to the checkout, anything will be highly appreciated, I don't know what else to google now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous options for tying PayPal into your website or app.  Depending on exactly what you're doing or how good you are with web service API's you may choose one or another.

If you want to keep things simple, you can stick with Payments Standard.  This is basically what you're referring to about the one item only buy now button, but you can use the [cart upload command method](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/) to build a form that includes multiple items and pass it all over to PayPal at once.

If you prefer web service API's I'd recommend using [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/#ec).  This consists of [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).  Read through that general EC documentation to get familiar with the calls and how it all flows.

Another thing I would highly recommend utilizing is [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).  This is a feature where PayPal will POST transaction data to a listener script that you have sitting on your server any time a transaction occurs on your PayPal account.  This includes payments, refunds, disputes, cleared payments that were pending, etc.  This allows you to automate tasks like updating your database, sending out custom email notifications, hitting 3rd party web services, etc. and it happens in real-time, so it's very powerful.